# query with result based on two tables without join

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

i want to create query in `Query Builder` The query should at least looks like (plus default typo3 fields hidden, deleted etc.):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        *
    FROM
        domain_model_topic,
        domain_model_post
    WHERE
        domain_model_topic.uid = domain_model_post.topic
            AND (domain_model_topic.title LIKE '%test%'
            OR domain_model_post.text LIKE '%test%')
```

Query is usage to search forum for selected word
In this query i have one variables from user: its text to search in topics and posts.

Based on documentation from https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/

i created something like:

```
    /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder $queryBuilder */
    $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('domain_model_topic');
    $queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeAll();
    $queryBuilder
        ->select('*')
        ->from('domain_model_post')
        ->from('domain_model_topic')
        ->where(
            $queryBuilder->expr()
                ->eq('domain_model_topic.uid', 'domain_model_post.topic') . ' AND ' .
            $queryBuilder->expr()
                ->like('domain_model_topic.title', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards($search->getSWord()) . '%')) . ' OR ' .
            $queryBuilder->expr()
                ->like('domain_model_post.text', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards($search->getSWord()) . '%'))
        );
    $test = $queryBuilder->execute()->fetchAll();
```

but this code cause error `Allowed memory size of XXX bytes exhausted` for any assigned number of memory

i tried rewrite query to have its simpler (without  `$queryBuilder->expr():` )

```
    $queryBuilder
        ->select('*')
        ->from('domain_model_post')
        ->from('domain_model_topic')
        ->where(
    "domain_model_topic.uid = domain_model_post.topic
    AND (domain_model_topic.title LIKE '%" . $variableStringFromUser . "%'
    OR domain_model_post.text LIKE '%" . $variableStringFromUser . "%')"
    );
```

And it work, but have seriously problems with security, then i tried do add `$queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($variableStringFromUser)`
and that didn't work

My goal is to create search by search word for forum for topics from one table and post from another. I can't use left join because its have seriously performance issue and after some test in mysql, select from two tables give best result (and work in mysql)

What can i do to create query from begining of post in typo3_8 (best with query builder) in secure way (and as clean as possible)

Comment: I tried some other way to realize my problem but nothing was correct. Its looks like main problem is with second `from()` because without it i can do search in secure way for topic

Comment: "domain_model_post" won't work, use "tx_siexpertforum_domain_model_post" instead. You have no alias defined.

Comment: Also a "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM a,b WHERE a.id=b.id_a" is technically equal to a "SELECT * FROM a JOIN b ON a.id=b.id_a GROUP BY a.id, b.id" which is fully supported by QueryBuilder and more common, too.

Comment: So I would stick with your first implementation where you correctly escaped user input and try it with JOIN. I have MUCH more complicated QueryBuilder queries and they are very light on memory overhead (10M or so including the Typo3 core). The rest of the memory should go into holding the fetched records in a PHP array structure. If you fetch MANY, you might have to split up your work.

Comment: Thanks for trying help in my problem :)
I found correct solution and i added it here in answers, if you want you can check what solution help me a loot. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long trying i found solution to create query which work fast.

```
    $queryBuilder
        ->select('*')
        ->from('domain_model_post')
        ->from('domain_model_topic')
        ->orWhere(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->like('domain_model_topic.title', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards($search->getSWord()) . '%')),
            $queryBuilder->expr()
                ->like('domain_model_post.text', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards($search->getSWord()) . '%'))
        )
        ->andWhere(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('domain_model_topic.uid', 'domain_model_post.topic')
        );
```

Query for this code:

```
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        `domain_model_post`,
        `domain_model_topic`
    WHERE
        ((`domain_model_topic`.`title` LIKE '%test%')
            OR (`domain_model_post`.`text` LIKE '%test%'))
            AND (`domain_model_topic`.`uid` = domain_model_post.topic)
```

its work hundred time faster than previous query. I recommend for everyone to try optimize searches by text with doable `from` and `where` instead of join